# Почему не приходят в attachments поле все фото. VK Bot Long Poll

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Я отсылаю сообщение в бот с 4 фото.

```
{
  group_id: 215232092,
  type: 'message_new',
  event_id: 'd8ca301fc687e939378dec955bcbcd1b2e13d4f2',
  v: '5.131',
  object: {
    message: {
      date: 1661079984,
      from_id: 294669508,
      id: 1416,
      out: 0,
      attachments: [Array],
      conversation_message_id: 1079,
      fwd_messages: [],
      important: false,
      is_hidden: false,
      peer_id: 294669508,
      random_id: 0,
      text: 'rere',
      is_cropped: true
    },
    client_info: {
      button_actions: [Array],
      keyboard: true,
      inline_keyboard: true,
      carousel: true,
      lang_id: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Приходит объект, в поле attachment одно фото, массив с 1 элементом.
Три фото работают нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть решение для api golang, проверьте поле is_cropped в объекте сообщения (обрезает сообщения для бота)
https://github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk/issues/196